# void * as a function parameter

Tags: c

I've problem using void *. How should I do to use this clean_buffer function for int and float arrays.

```
void clean_buffer( void *ptr, int n)
{
    for( int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        ptr[i]=0;
}
int main(void)
{
   float  *pf;
   int    *pi;

   pf = (float *) malloc(10*sizeof(float));
   pi = (int *)malloc(10*sizeof(int));


   clean_buffer( (float *)pf, 10);
   clean_buffer( (int *)pi, 10);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use [memset](https://linux.die.net/man/3/memset) instead of clean_buffer? Conveniently enough IEEE 754 ensures that zeroing a float buffer will set the values to 0.0f.

Comment: You could pass the size of the buffer in **bytes** instead. But at that point you are writing a less efficient `memset`. So just use *that*.

Comment: You never need to cast anything to its own type, like in `(float *)pf`.

Comment: Also, is your goal here to zero the buffers immediately after they are allocated? If this is the case, you could use [calloc](https://linux.die.net/man/3/calloc) which initializes memory to zero for you.

Comment: @SirDarius From the title it seems that it is about usage of `void*` pointers in general with the snippet only being a MCVE for illustration.

Comment: @Gerhardh while the title is generic, the question itself is pretty specific, and borders an X-Y problem (asking about a solution, and not about the problem to solve, ie. zeroing arrays). My questions ask for clarification from OP to make sure it is indeed the case.

Answer (score 2):

*void* is a non value you cannot use `*((void*) x) = v;` and to use a *cast* to use a pointer to an other type is **dangerous** because the size may not be the same

But, in your case you set to 0, so you can use *memset* or replace the *malloc* my *calloc* and it is useless to have `clean_buffer` :

```
int main(void)
{
   float  *pf;
   int    *pi;

   pf = calloc(10, sizeof(float));
   pi = calloc(10, sizeof(int));

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `clean_buffer()` is not always useless.  A block that ends with `{ void *p; ... memset(p, 0, 10); }` is subject to optimization dropping the `memset()` call.  The `clean_buffer()` may be there to scrub memory from a security point of view.  Likely `volatile` should be applied too to prevent it from being optimized out.

Comment: @chux In the current case _calloc_ is certainly the best way ;-)

Comment: OP's post is not certain the usage of `clean_buffer()` is solely for the first assignment.  `clean_buffer(p, n)` may be called though  out `p` lifetime.

Comment: `calloc()` is good and preferable if the goal is only initialization to 0,  Consider `pf = calloc(10, sizeof *pf);` as easier to code right, review and maintain.

Answer (score 2):

Type `void` has no size. Therefore you cannot use `void *` to clear an array.
You can not dereference that type for the same reason.

You must cast to a pointer with specific type:

```
void clean_buffer(void *ptr, size_t n)
{
    unsigned char *my_ptr = ptr;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        my_ptr[i]=0;
}
```

You need to take care that the size passed to your function cannot be the number or arrays because the compiler cannot do pointer arithmetics with `void*` pointers.
And for sizes you should use `size_t`

Instead you have to pass the size of the array in bytes:

```
int main(void)
{
   float  *pf;
   int    *pi;

   pf = malloc(10*sizeof(float));
   pi = malloc(10*sizeof(int));

   clean_buffer( pf, 10*sizeof(float));
   clean_buffer( pi, 10*sizeof(int));

   return 0;
}
```

Or you need to pass any other information that can be used to determine type and/or size of the data.

Also:
Casting the return value of `malloc` is not needed in C.
Casting the parameters of `clean_buffer` to a type that the variable already has, is useless. The pointer type is converted to `void *` anyway as this is what the function expects.

Note:
Other answers and comments mention that you could simply pass the pointer to `memset` or use `calloc` etc.
This might be true for this very specific case but if you want to do anything else than simply zeroing the memory, the same aspects regarding `void *` pointers apply as I have shown here. And in those cases `memset` or `calloc` are of no help.

Answer (score 1):

> I've problem using void *. How should I do to use this clean_buffer function for int and float arrays (?)

Others have mentioned useful things like the need to `sizeof` to find the size, cast not needed and alternatives to use `calloc()` for a zero initialized memory allocation.

---

To add:

**sizeof *object_pointer**

Use `sizeof *object_pointer` to find the size.  It is less error prone, easier to review and maintain than coding in the type.

```
// clean_buffer( (float *)pf, 10);
// clean_buffer( (int *)pi, 10);

// cast not needed
clean_buffer(pf, sizeof *pf * 10);  // No need to mention type!
clean_buffer(pi, sizeof *pi * 10);
```

**volatile**

Scrubbing memory after its final use is prone to being optimized out and then a good reason to **not** use `memset()` when memory security is of concern.  Instead use `volatile` to prevent `clean_buffer()` from itself being optimized out.

```
void clean_buffer(void *ptr, size_t n) {
  volatile unsigned char *vuc = ptr;
  for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    vuc[i]=0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cast `ptr` to the appropriate type so it can dereferenced to clear what it points to; something you know points to a type that you want to clear `i` items of.

Answer (score 0):

> void clean_buffer( void *ptr, int n)

This function demands a void * as a parameter.

> clean_buffer( (float *)pf, 10);

Here you are casting to a float pointer. So this a different type as demanded

Also void has no size, so you cant really use [] on ptr

Answer (score 0):

`malloc` itself returns a void pointer as it doesn't really know for which type you are allocating memory. So, you need to use the same size which you pass to `malloc` for clearing the buffer also.

You can use `memset` and pass the size of the entire buffer to clear it without having to worry about it's type.

```
void clean_buffer( void *ptr, size_t n)
{
    memset(ptr, 0, n)
}
int main(void)
{
   float  *pf;
   int    *pi;

   pf = (float *) malloc(10*sizeof(float));
   pi = (int *)malloc(10*sizeof(int));


   clean_buffer(pf, 10*sizeof(float));
   clean_buffer(pi, 10*sizeof(int));

    return 0;
}
```

Additionally, as others have suggested, you can use `calloc` if it suits you.